# Confusion on a differential notation

Tags: analysis, notation

This is a notation I see in page 8 of [Guy Barles and Espen R. Jakobsen](http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/~barles/rateParHJB6.pdf), namely
$$
\partial_t^{\beta_0}D^{\beta'}\phi(x,t)
$$
where $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n\times[0,T]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, $\beta_0\in \mathbb{N}$ , $\beta'=(\beta'_i)_i \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

I want to know the precise definition of the notation.

Comment: It means one differentiates the function $\beta_0$ times with respect to $t$ and $\beta'_i$ times with respect to each $x_i$.

Comment: @Piau Thanks a lot. It makes so much sense now

Comment: Now I'm curious, why are you reading a paper on differential equations without knowing that notation?

Answer (score 1):

The notation means that one differentiates the function $\beta_0$ times with respect to $t$ and $\beta'_i$ times with respect to each $x_i$.